# What is "Afterglow" in Gamma-Ray Bursts and how is it caused?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, gamma-rays

[This](https://imagine.gsfc.nasa.gov/science/featured_science/grb_anniv.html) talks about "Afterglow" of a Gamma-Ray Burst. What exactly is an Afterglow? And how do we use these to detect GRBs(Gamma-Ray Bursts)?

Answer (score 0):

the "afterglow" consists of x-rays which fade out much more slowly than the initial gamma burst. The combination of sudden gamma burst + slowly fading x-ray "tail" furnishes clues about what caused the burst. Best guesses currently are neutron star + neutron star merger to form a black hole, neutron star + black hole merger to form a bigger black hole, and supermassive star collapse & formation of a black hole.

Comment: In the first line you talk about X-rays...where do those x-rays come from? Moreover, let me know if I got this correctly - So basically we measure the X-rays from the afterglow right? And, What causes this "Glow" in the question?

Comment: gamma rays have a characteristic energy typical of processes occurring inside atomic nuclei, so when nuclei get ripped up, gamma rays are the signal announcing this. X-rays have a characteristic energy typical of deep electron orbitals in heavier elements like iron, nickel, cobalt, copper, etc. so when violence is done to the electron orbitals, X-rays are given off. This means that if you shred up nuclei, out come the gammas, and as the fragments collect themselves and form up into atoms again, out come the X-rays. More in next comment.

Comment: The characteristic time scales for anything involving the nucleus are super-quick so the gamma rays come out as a sudden flash. the X-rays are generated more slowly so the afterglow lasts for minutes to hours. This explanation is grossly simplified for your shopping convenience.